# Selenium can't reach chrome in celery task while using supervisor

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, celery, supervisord

I have a Django project that uses Celery as a task queue. The task is about running a chromedriver by Selenium and fetching data from some URLs. like this:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def task_one(self):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.get('https://somewhere.com')
    # do others
```

This task should be run periodically, for that I use celery beat.

for testing, I run celery worker and celery beat in two terminals and everything seems okay. (the celery beat sends every 20 seconds and the worker runs Chrome and fetches data)

But when I use Supervisor, the worker goes wrong and can't reach Chrome. (Still celery beat works well and sends every 20 seconds but the problem is in the worker)

The celery logs say:

```
'Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x562b0da106c3 <unknown>
#1 0x562b0d6e61e7 <unknown>
#2 0x562b0d719526 <unknown>
#3 0x562b0d71569c <unknown>
#4 0x562b0d75823a <unknown>
#5 0x562b0d74ee93 <unknown>
#6 0x562b0d721934 <unknown>
#7 0x562b0d72271e <unknown>
#8 0x562b0d9d5cc8 <unknown>
#9 0x562b0d9d9c00 <unknown>
#10 0x562b0d9e41ac <unknown>
#11 0x562b0d9da818 <unknown>
#12 0x562b0d9a728f <unknown>
#13 0x562b0d9fee98 <unknown>
#14 0x562b0d9ff069 <unknown>
#15 0x562b0da0f853 <unknown>
#16 0x7f0c29a97b43 <unknown>
'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by specifying the chromedriver path with following parametrs.

Since i run my script on ubuntu server it looks like this:

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--block-images")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver"
    service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,
                                   options=chrome_options)
```